# Difficult C# if then logic

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Object is forced up. After 10 seconds, object will be forced back down. Alternatively, object can be clicked and thereby forced back down before 10 seconds has elapsed.

**What is currently happening:** If object is forced down, GAME OVER.

**What I am trying to do instead:** If object is forced down before you are able to click it, GAME OVER.

In other words, the GAME OVER is being shown in 10 seconds, regardless of whether or not the object was clicked.

I'm having a really difficult time with this logic and I am hoping a fresh perspective might be able to help.

```
public void FixedUpdate() {
    // Increase the kick timer 
    kickTimer += Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    // If the next kick time has came
    if (nextKick < kickTimer) {
        // Schedule the kick back corresponding to the current kick
        nextKickBacks.Enqueue (nextKick + 10f);

        // Apply the kick force
        rb.AddForce (transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);

        // Plan the next kick
        nextKick = kickTimer + Random.Range (MinKickTime, MaxKickTime);
    }


    // If there are more kick backs to go, and the time of the closest one has came
    if (0 < nextKickBacks.Count) {
        if (nextKickBacks.Peek () < kickTimer) {
                // Apply the kick back force
                rb.AddForce (-transform.up * thrust, ForceMode.Impulse);
// Show the GAME OVER gameObject                
GameObject.Find ("icetextureONfile").transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.02f, 0.02f, 0.02f);
                // Dequeue the used kick back time
                nextKickBacks.Dequeue ();

        }
    }

}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    rb.AddForce(-transform.up * thrust,ForceMode.Impulse); 
}

}
```

Comment: *"regardless of whether or not the object was clicked"* Is there any conditional behaviour, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the logic for what happens when you click on the object. Right now you are applying force, but there is nothing in the code changing the state of the Update loop.

I don't know what type of game you are making. So I am not sure what you want to do when the click is executed, but I am guessing you want to reset the kickbacks.

In that way you can do something like this. Change .Clear() to whatever method suits your needs.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    rb.AddForce(-transform.up * thrust,ForceMode.Impulse); 

    nextKick = 0; // reset timer to force a new kick to be set next frame
    nextKickBacks.Clear(); // clear current set kickbacks
}
```

Comment: You're exactly right I was thinking about it all wrong. Thank you